# Android Custom Action bar not filling parent, title not center aligned

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-actionbar

I have been experimenting the following issue: I have created a custom action bar:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/com_facebook_blue" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/app_title"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which is inflated by a GraphicsBuilder class in the following way:

```
public static void setupActionBar(String title, Activity a) {

        final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) a.getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.action_bar_layout, null);
        final ActionBar actionBar = a.getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
        final int actionBarColor = a.getResources().getColor(R.color.main_red);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(actionBarColor));

        TextView tv = (TextView) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(a.getAssets(), "fonts/Molle-Regular.ttf");
        tv.setText(title);
        tv.setTypeface(font);
    }
```

Which leads to the following results (I have kept the title bar background blue to highlight the issue):

[image]

Basically it looks like that the custom action bar does not fill the parent width, therefore any try to align the title at the center is useless. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10):

I know this is a long time gone.
Solved it by changing the layout params once it's been set as custom view.

My logic was that when you inflate it the first time, it assumes the size of the original container.
When you call:

```
actionBar.setCustomView(titlebar);
```

It's already got its dimensions preset.
My solution was:

```
View titlebar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titlebar, null);

// Do stuff to Title Bar //

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(titlebar);
View v = actionBar.getCustomView();
LayoutParams lp = v.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
v.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Alternatively, you can first set the action bar layout without the inflater:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.id.titlebar);
View v = actionBar.getCustomView();
// Do something to the view  E.g Set button listeners blah //

// Rest of code
```

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered! +1

Comment: how to do this with support action bar?

Comment: change "getActionBar()" to "getSupportActionBar()"
Make sure you're referencing the support library in your imports

Comment: for anyone seeing this, supported action bar won't work in this way, you need to set toolbar setContentInsetsAbsolute method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172439/match-parent-doesnt-work-for-custom-actionbar .