# match_parent doesn't work for custom actionbar

Tags: android

I try to implement a custom action bar. Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/action_bar">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="test "/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And here is the java code:

```
public class CustomActionBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

        View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
        Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) customView.getParent();
        parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);

    }
}
```

The result is:
[image]

Here is the result with "developer options" > "show layout bounds"

[image]

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: that's because you're inflating with "null" as the parent

Comment: what it should be @Muhannad?

Comment: will i don't know , but one way to solve your problem is to set the layout parameters of your custom view programatically

Comment: @Phil notice the background of framelayout doesn't expand to entire parent's width or height.

Comment: @Muhannad I prefer my layouts to be inside of xml as much as possible.

Comment: keep the layout in xml,but just use setLayoutParams for the parent to make it match_parent

Comment: @Muhannad it worked thanks. It's the second bug I encounter in android sdk this week. How should I accept your answer. I'm not a stackoverflow expert.

Comment: any way you can click on the flag/upVote icon

Comment: and it's not android sdk bug it's just how it's supposed to work wen you inflate the view without a parent it will ignore the layoutParams

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Muhannad Fakhouri in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172439/match-parent-doesnt-work-for-custom-actionbar?noredirect=1#comment48451292_30172439) pointed out. I needed to add layout params programatically. Layout params will be ignored if the layout inflated without specifying the parent. Here is the updated code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

        View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
        customView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
        Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) customView.getParent();
        parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin**

*Do not need to enable or disable somethings*. Just need to call parent of your custom actionBar view and **set content instest absolute**. You can use this function:

```
fun setMyCustomActionBar(view: View?) {
    val params = ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    supportActionBar?.displayOptions = ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
    view?.let {
        supportActionBar?.setCustomView(view, params)
        val parent: Toolbar = view.parent as Toolbar
        parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0) //<-- Just this is important.
    }
}
```

Do not forget import Toolbar library:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```